# How to checked multiple checkbox over loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

In One Array I am getting array like :

```
    ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

And In another array i Am getting array like :

```
    ['1','6']
```

In template i am doing like :

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
      {% if edit_data.features %}
    {% for feature in edit_data.feature %}
    {% for features in edit_data.features %}
    {% if feature.id == features.feature_id %}
        checked='checked'
    {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value={{feature.id}} {{checked}}> {{feature.name}}
    {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}                    
    </div>
```

After This i am getting Like:

How Can i select the checkbox over the loop i am not able to create variable inside if condition. i am newbe please let me now how can i make checkbox to be selected

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzVV4.png
```

After Your Solution i am getting Like This:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nZJj.png

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
      {% if edit_data.features %}
        {% for feature in edit_data.feature %}
            {% with ns=namespace(found=false) %}
            {% for features in edit_data.features %}
                {% if feature.id == features.feature_id %}
                    {% with ns.found=true %}
                {% endif %}
            {%endfor%}
        {% if ns.found == true %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="features" value={{feature.id}}  checked> {{feature.name}}</option>
        {% else %}
           <input type="checkbox" name="features" value={{feature.id}} > {{feature.name}}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {%endfor%}
      {%endif%}                    
    </div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207916/discussion-on-answer-by-dontbe3greedy-how-to-checked-multiple-checkbox-over-loop).